# How could we search for an exact match for a word/ words in java using regex? These words could includes parenthesis, curly braces etc

Tags: java, regex

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    findExactWord find = new findExactWord();

    String fullString = "reports of a chemical (reaction; in the kitchen) area found a male employee suffering from nausea";

    System.out.println(find.isContainExactWord(fullString, "chemical (reaction; in the kitchen)"));

}

private boolean isContainExactWord(String fullString, String partWord){
    String pattern = "\\b"+partWord+"\\b";
    System.out.println("Pattern : "+partWord);
    Pattern p=Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m=p.matcher(fullString);
    return m.find();
}
```

I want this result to be - true.

Search input is : "chemical (reaction; in the kitchen)

this should search all characters exactly as is.

output is now : false

Comment: I am not sure what you are really trying to accomplish here. It seems like you don't want to use regex, so why not use `contains` method from String instead?

Comment: Only `String pattern = "(?<!\\S)"+Pattern.quote(partWord)+"(?!\\S)";`

Comment: I can use contains method, but the problem is, it won't give the exact result. LIke String s = "abc defg"; s.contains("abc d") will return true here. I want the exact match, and in this case this should return false

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this   String pattern = "(?<!\\S)"+Pattern.quote(partWord)+"(?!\\S)";     seems producing the expected result.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like the only solution. Word boundaries like whitespace, unambiguous or regular word boundaries are very broadly-covered topic on SO. Just google a bit using these terms.

Comment: @jaco Can your data have text in quotations? If yes what should be result for `isContainExactWord("abc 'de fg' h", "de fg")`?

Comment: Or simpler case: should `find.isContainExactWord("a 'b' c", "b")` return `true` or `false`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is there any way to improve the performance. It take almost 600 sec when String.contains() takes only 16 sec. Of course string.contains() is not giving the o/p as expected

Comment: @Pshemo It should return true. It should search the input  word as it's, we should get the exact match of the input as output.

Answer (score -1):

```
String pattern = partWord;
System.out.println("Pattern : " + partWord);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.LITERAL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(fullString);
return m.find();
```

now the tested version ;-) 
it matches special characters and ignores newlines

Comment: Can you explain what problem does it solve?

Comment: the output will be true in the example op provided. he specified that he wants to use regex and not String.contains like you suggested.

Comment: "the output will be true in the example op provided", no it will not: https://ideone.com/jDaZ5N. "he specified that he wants to use regex" I don't know where you get that from. Just because OP used it in his example doesn't mean he wants it, it may also mean that OP may not be aware of other approaches.

Comment: In particular it doesn't work with OP's search string because the parenthesis are parsed as grouping parenthesis.

Comment: Also `find()` method doesn't require from regex to match entire string. It is `matches()` method that has this requirement so surrounding `.*` doesn't change anything here (not to mention it will fail if string will contain many lines, since `.` by default doesn't match line separators like `\r` or `\n`).

Comment: @Pshemo i present you the title of the question: How could we search for an exact match for a word/ words in java **using regex**?

Comment: OK fair enough. But still this answer doesn't improve OP situation (see my latest comment).

Comment: i edited the answer to ignore special characters

Comment: `Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.LITERAL);` that would also make `.*` into literal. Please test your solution first before posting it.

Comment: Later in comments OP clarified why he can't use contains method (which is basically what your current solution is). From [OP comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58768758/how-could-we-search-for-an-exact-match-for-a-word-words-in-java-using-regex-th#comment103824080_58768758): "*problem is, it won't give the exact result. LIke String s = "abc defg"; s.contains("abc d") will return true*". In other words, OP wants to avoid matching `cat` in words like `catastrophe`.

Comment: @ikari.shinji This solution is not searching for the exact word. It str="abc defogs", search("abc de") return false rather than true here.